# Ansible ec2_fact documentation

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, ansible

I have searched far and wide to try and find some decent documentation relating to Ansible's `ec2_facts` module, specifically related to the variables which are created by this module. However, I can't seem to find anything. It looks like there is are variables called `ansible_ec2_instance_id` and `ansible_ec2_instance_type` which are created but I'm looking for a comprehensive list of all of the variables which are generated by this module.

Is there any way to print out the variables stored by `ec2_facts` with the debug module?

I have tried this:

```
- name: Get the ec2 facts of this instance
  debug:
      ec2_facts:
```

but that throws a syntax exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this documentaion](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_module.html) and bear in mind that all variables will be created with the `ansible_ec2_` prefix.

I.e.:

`instance_id` --> `ansible_ec2_instance_id`

Comment: That was my initial guess - however that's not the case. There's no ansible_ec2_region variable as one would expect.

Answer (score 0):

That might help you.

```
- hosts: ec2
  gather_facts: yes
  connection: local
  vars: 
    - region: 'us-west-2'
  tasks:
    - name: Gather EC2 facts
      local_action: ec2_facts
      register: ec2facts

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ec2facts }}"
```